# is there function or method for find specific point with details in points cloud

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

i am trying to draw map marker on point cloud. add marker on point cloud there need the elevation of that point or near by point to show marker on point cloud. am give elevation zero but on zero elevation marker not show on point cloud.

```
var marker ={lat: 20.008482, lng: 73.756834 }
var point = this.viewer.getHeightAt(marker.lat, marker.lng)
console.log('point data', point)
```

result expected `point data {x:41455.54542,y:452157.215, z:442.44}`